# How to do a post-build task based off the exit code of the build script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-build-flow

I want to be able to read the exit code of the build script, from my post-build script.
Is there a way to do that in Jenkins configuration?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

it will allow me to check for a matching string (in this case 'hella success rn') but it won't let me see the exit code of the build script?

Comment: Does my answer addresses your query?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `#!/bin/sh` at the start of your `Execute shell` block as shown below:

[image]

Using `#!/bin/sh` without the default options that Jenkins uses i.e., `#!/bin/sh -xe` will *prevent* Jenkins from marking your `Execute shell` as failure. Doing this will help you run the subsequent command of finding the return status of your script.

```
-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

Ref: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html

Based on the return status (`script_status=$?`) of your script, print something that you can search later in your post-build step.

Then, in the `Post-build Actions`, search that printed text to decide your *post-build* action as shown below:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]